# go elastic sum text field

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I want to sum up filed price, but got error "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default."
This is my code:

```
sumAgg := elastic.NewSumAggregation().Field("price")
q := query.Must(elastic.NewRangeQuery("price").Gt(0))
res, err := p.config.ElasticClient.Search().Index(idx).Query(q).Aggregation("sum", sumAgg).Size(0).Do(ctx)
```

This is the mapping:

```
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "price": {
        "type": "scaled_float",
        "scaling_factor": 100000
      },
    }
}
```

Anybody can help?

Comment: can you show your complete query in JSON format, esp aggregation part and show your complete mapping. you are using `price` which is of type numeric where `doc_values` are enabled by default  so you shouldn't get this exception. can you try hitting the same JSON query direct to ES??

Answer (score 0):

By default field data is disabled on text fields and a [detailed reason is mentioned here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/fielddata.html#fielddata-disabled-text-fields) , as it's very costly on text fields and mainly require for aggregations(your use-case), read more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/fielddata.html)

from official doc

> Instead, text fields use a query-time in-memory data structure called
> fielddata. This data structure is built on demand the first time that
> a field is used for aggregations, sorting, or in a script. It is built
> by reading the entire inverted index for each segment from disk,
> inverting the term ↔︎ document relationship, and storing the result in
> memory, in the JVM heap.

Make sure, a field which you are using in your aggregation has this enabled. for numeric fields [doc_values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html) are used for aggregation and its enabled on by default on the numeric field.